# Different value displaying in Razor textbox than is in model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm having an issue where a value I set in the model is incorrect when accessing it from the Razor code.  If I place a breakpoint on the if statement below and inspect `Model.TestVal`, it contains the correct value.  However, that value is not what is displayed in the generated text box, and I can't figure out why the two are different.

```
    @if (Model.IsValid)
    {
        <div class="testRow">
            <label class="testLabel" for="TestVal">Test Value:</label>
            <div class="testField" id="TestVal">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TestVal, ViewHelper.IsEditable("TestVal"))</div>
        </div>
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TextBoxFor` helper will first look at the value in the ModelState and after that the value in your model. It's a common gotcha when people try to change some model property value in a POST action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
{
    model.SomeProperty = "some new value";
    return View(model);
}
```

In this case the new value will not be taken into account because the ModelState already contains the originally POSTed value and that's what will be displayed by the TextBoxFor helper. To make this work you will also need to remove the original value from the model state:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
{
    ModelState.Remove("SomeProperty");
    model.SomeProperty = "some new value";
    return View(model);
}
```

or completely wipe it out:

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

Comment: Is there any way to force it to use the value from my model? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Yes, there's a way, see my updated answer. You just need to remove it from the ModelState. And no, you are not doing anything wrong. It's just how those helpers are designed to work.